# Orthonormal Basis and evaluation of expression

Tags: vectors, orthonormal

Let the vectors $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ be specified by

$$\mathbf{a} = -3\mathbf{e_1} + 2\mathbf{e_2} - 8\mathbf{e_3}$$

$$\mathbf{b} =  5\mathbf{e_1} - 7\mathbf{e_2} + 3\mathbf{e_3}$$

where $\{\mathbf{e_i}\}$ is an orthonormal basis. Evaluate the expression:

$$\Psi = \frac{a_ib_ia_jb_j - a_ka_kb_lb_l}{a_ma_m}$$

Please help me here. How can we utilize $\mathbf{e_1}, \mathbf{e_2}, \mathbf{e_3}$ vectors here to find the value. I have no idea as how to proceed.

Comment: I don't understand. What are $a_i,a_j,a_k,a_m$?

Comment: $\Psi$ depends on $i,j,k,l,m$. And: is $i\ne j\ne k\ne l\ne m$?